# Objective C protocol as an equal to Java Interface?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, interface

The question is not only regarding the headline, but more of a "how will I achieve this, without trying to force a Java/Flash design into an Objective C (iPhone)program".

I have 6 views that extends UIView, these views all have different behavior but share certain methods, like `-(void) update` and `-(void) changeState:(NSInteger)state`.

A viewController, whose job is it to update, instantiate and display these views has a switch block to do this. So switch(4) {...} instantiates UIView4, but as I need a reference to the currently instantiated view (to do `update` and `changeState:`), I have a UIView property on my ViewController called self.currentView. As the instantiated UIView4 extends UIView I can easily go `[self.currentView addSubview:UIView4instance]` and then release the UIView4instance.

Now how will I call the `[UIView4instance update]` method on the view? or the `[UIView5instance changeState]` etc. etc.
Since I added it to `self.currentView` which is of type UIView it no longer has any reason to believe it has an `update` or `changeState:` method, meaning I cannot iterate the views and send them these messages.

This approach brings on a ton of other problems, I would need to test and typeCast my views each time I needed to do any operations on them.

If I were doing something like this Composite Pattern approach in, say, Java. I would either write an interface that all the views (UIView1, UIview2.... UIViewN) would implement. Or maybe an abstract class that all the views inherited the `changeState:` and `update` methods from.

This way I could have `self.currentView` just know that I'm adding objects to your view and they all conform to these methods.

The two solutions I can think of, with my very small Objective-C experience is:
doing it with delegation or categories, but this seems overkill in every way :/
I guess I could also extend UIView and then extend my class extending UIView again, but there is probably a reason Objective-C does not directly support abstract classes...

Hope someone could point me in the right direction regarding these issues.
Thanks:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is equal. You can declare a protocol

```
@protocol MyViewProtocol
-(void)update;
-(void)changeState:(NSInteger)state;
@end
```

and declare your subclasses like

```
@interface MyUIView3 : UIView<MyViewProtocol> {
....
}
....
@end
```

Then, the declaration

```
UIView<MyViewProtocol>* view=[[MyUIView3 alloc] init];
```

means that `view` is an instance (of a subclass of) `UIView` which also conforms to `MyViewProtocol`. 
Just the way it works in Java, I think. See [the apple doc on protocols](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html).

Comment: Hi Yuji Thanks! this is great, it is like I have done with delegation a few times, I just couldn't "translate" that approach into the simple solution you present here. I'll try it out straight away!

Answer (score 4):

One thing to be aware of is that while defining a protocol like this is a convenience and certainly makes things clearer, it is by no means *necessary* to make your solution work. Objective-C binds methods at runtime, and so all you really *need* to do is to make sure all your view classes implement the methods you care about and call them.

You will get a complier warning for this, but it *will* work.

Now, in general it's probably preferable to define a protocol like this and it's what I generally do. But it's also important to remember that runtime binding is there and can be incredibly powerful.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the input.
I did get a runtime error because I had self.currentView cast as a UIView.
So you say that I could have cast my currentView as *id* and then just sent it the message any ways?

Comment: You don't have to cast it as anything. You can send any message to any object at any time. You may get a compiler warning, but it will work if the class implements the method. If it doesn't you'll get an error, unless you also implement -forwardInvocation. You should read the documentation for that in the NSObject documentation, it's pretty enlightening.